# Detect navigation bar: resource (navexposed, navhidden)

Tags: android, android-resources, navigationbar

Android supports resources, which will be applied depending on navigation bar.
[According to the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#NavAvailQualifier) "values-navexposed" folder will be used if navigation bar is visible, "values-navhidden" folder otherwise.
**How to use it correctly?**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    float floatValue = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.test_float);
}
```

dimensions.xml (/res/values-navexposed and /res/values-navhidden):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item format="float" type="dimen" name="test_float">1</item>
</resources>
```

The exception is:

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030000

Comment: Have you ensured that the resource is also available in the default configuration? As stated in the documentation: `When defining an alternative resource, make sure you also define the resource in a default configuration.`
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources